# Change View height on state selected

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android so this question might be dumb but, is it possible to change layout_height on a View through selector? I'm trying to make a custom TabHost/TabWidget where I have to change some views depending on their select state. This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_selected="true" android:height="10dp" />
    <item android:height="5dp" />
</selector>
```

And then I'm trying to append this selector to View like this:

```
<View android:layout_height="@drawable/tab_lineheight_selector" ... />
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong cuz my app keeps crashing. Is it even possible?

Comment: Well I know it crashes but I don't know why system doesn't pull height from selector. Here's the error report: "Binary XML file line #18: You must supply a layout_height attribute."

Answer (score 1):

As per developer docs:

> **android:layout_height**
>
> Specifies the basic height of the view. This is a required attribute
>   for any view inside of a containing layout manager. Its value may be a
>   dimension (such as "12dip") for a constant height or one of the
>   special constants. May be a dimension value, which is a floating point
>   number appended with a unit such as "14.5sp". Available units are: px
>   (pixels), dp (density-independent pixels), sp (scaled pixels based on
>   preferred font size), in (inches), mm (millimeters). This may also be
>   a reference to a resource (in the form "@[package:]type:name") or
>   theme attribute (in the form "?[package:][type:]name") containing a
>   value of this type.

So, technically its **NOT POSSIBLE** what you are trying to do.

Comment: So I'll have to implement a listener and then on click fetch the tabWidget and change height of the view in side of it? Or is there any other more elegant way of changing views height on selection changed?

Comment: doing it programmatically is your best bet